# Looking for module- percent fee on specific product when payed by card

Tags: checkout

I'm looking for a module that can solve the following problem.

I need to apply 3% fee for a specific product when payed by card. And the main condition is I need it to apply 3% only on that product (type, category) and not on entire cart on checkout.

Any suggestions?